# jQuery. Mi modal no se cierra con boton personalizado

Tags: jquery, modal

tengo un modal, al que le he puesto un boton para cerrarlo (ocultarlo sin destruirlo vaya).

Este es mi modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mediumModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mediumModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    {{-- <span aria-hidden="true">&times</span>--}}
                    Hola mundo
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="mediumBody">
                <div>
                    <p>Tú correo: <b>{{auth()->user()->email}}</b></p>
                    <p>Contenido del mensaje: </p>
                    <form action="">
                        @csrf @method('post')
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea style="resize: none;" id="contenido_mensaje" rows="10" class="form-control"
                                name="contenido" placeholder="Contenido del mensaje"></textarea>
                            <label id="counter_char"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group text-center">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_enviar_mensaje">
                                Enviar mensaje
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group text-center">
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="button" data-dismiss="modal"
                                aria-label="Close" data-backdrop="false">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">Cerrar ventana</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Me sale arriba a la derecha una cruz que si cierra el modal, la cual la estoy intentando quitar pero no me hace ni caso, pero bueno, ahora estoy con el **button** cerrar ventana:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" data-backdrop="false">
    <span aria-hidden="true">Cerrar ventana</span>
</button>
```

Para que cierre le he puesto los **data-*** necesarios y los aria que he visto tenia el boton por defecto del modal, pero aun asi lo ignora totalmente. Si tiene lo mismo no deberia de hacer lo mismo ?

Comment: Te faltó indicarle qué modal debe cerrar, no? `data-target="#mediumModal"`

Comment: @Benito-B Lo he probado asi pero tampoco va, es raro.

Answer (score 0):

He cambiado el boton customizado por esto:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" rel="modal:close" href="#close-modal">
    Cerrar ventana
</a>
```

He visto que al renderizar la vista, se crea un elemento con esas caracteristicas, ese boton es el encargado de cerrarlo.